# Real Time Progress Indicator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the real time progress indicator.

In the code snippet below,i am trying to set the width of DIV on the basis of the Number of Items retrieve from the Web Service Call Back Function.

```
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        table += '<tr>';
        table += '<td>' + data[i].ItemId + '</td>';
        table += '<td></td>';
        table += '<td>' + data[i].Name + '</td>';
        table += '<td>' + data[i].Unit + '</td>';
        table += '<td><input type=text value=' + data[i].Quantity + '></td>';
        table += '<td>' + data[i].Brands + '</td>';
        table += '<td><img border=0 src=../images/Delete_icon.gif></td>';
        table += '</tr>';

        $('#divProgressIndicator').width((100 * (i / data.length)) + '%');

    }
```

As shown in the code above,after the for loop is executed i only see the divProgressIndicator filled with the background color and I am not able to see the progress.
Can I achieve this in a for loop or i need to use some thing else.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Well the first thing is that you are updating the #divProgressIndicator for each iteration, so the last time it goes through it is '(100 * 1) %' which will give you the 100% and subsequently fill the div.

What you need is to have this ((total number of row / number of rows done) * 100) %. This will be done outside of the for loop

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, and maybe I misunderstood the problem at the first place, but what is the difference between setting the final width in the last iteration of the loop and setting it outside of the loop?

Comment: The loop is iterating through data, on the final pass through it will calculate the percentage of the width in this way: number of times through the loop / total number of items in the loop * 100. This is can be simplified to 1*100 so no matter what the progress is, it will be set to 100. I may be misunderstanding this as well though. I guess I am approaching this from the idea that the process may not be done yet when the user visits the page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own progressbar you might want to consider using the jquery progressbar, for more info see http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar.

Regarding your code I do not completely understand what is the exact html and what is the exact problem, but in my opinion to create a progressbar you need two divs, positioned absolute on the same spot, with one being fixed width and transparent (or a lower z-index) and borders, while the second div should have a color and should vary the width based on the progress.

If you do have such a setup, and your problem is that only the background div is displayed, then the cause is that background div is on top of the progress div, and the solution is either to set the background div to be transparent or set the progress div to be on top by setting it's z-index to a higher value.